# Unable to knit RMarkdown document to pdf due to Latex equation error

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex

I'm currently trying to knit a RMarkdown document to pdf, however, I keep getting an error.  I've managed to figure out which bit of my code is causing the error, however, the code is displaying correctly when I preview the file or knit it to a html file.  I can knit the file to pdf when I remove this block of code, but not sure why it won't work correctly.  Here is the code:

```
$$
\begin{align}
  R_{t+1} &= R_{t} + \alpha R_{t} - \beta R_{t}F_{t} \label{eq1} \tag{1} \\
  F_{t+1} &= F_{t} + \beta R_{t}F_{t} - \gamma F_{t} \label{eq2} \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
```

And here is the error I get:

**! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.**

Further to the error, I've tried to altering the code to the following:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
  R_{t+1} &= R_{t} + \alpha R_{t} - \beta R_{t}F_{t} \label{eq1} \tag{1} \\
  F_{t+1} &= F_{t} + \beta R_{t}F_{t} - \gamma F_{t} \label{eq2} \tag{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
```

However, when I do this, the equation doesn't display correctly in the html document.

Comment: You don't need to use the `$$`, it is enough to just use the `align` environment

Comment: I actually think the removal of the $$ has fixed another issue I was having - it didn't seem to want o print to pdf if I included the \tag{1} and \tag{2} clauses.  As soon as I removed the $$ dollars, it worked, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue by adding this code to the YAML section of the document:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: When using latex, do you have to download packages or files in order to use libraries? I don't use latex, but it always comes up within Rmarkdown. Thanks

Comment: I don't install any additional packages when using latex within R, although I have some sort of Latex software installed on my Pc (MikTex, Texlive etc).